# PHP 'Delete all between' specific words

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have a list of items. Each item has its description (the description is different for each item, but its structure remains the same) that looks kind of like that:

```
[description] => Flat sandal <br />Blush<br />Laminated leather<br />Intertwining straps<br />Low heel: 0.5cm<br />

        Product code: 5276870PS006703 <br /> Made in: Italy<br />Composition: 100%Calfskin
```

I need to delete the part "Product code: (random numbers and letters)" for every item description. I thought about using string_replace, but it would only work for replacing the words 'Product code', but not the numbers and letters, because they are different for every item. I also tried:

```
$description = delete_all_between("Product code:", "<br />", $description);
```

But it didn't work. 
Not sure what else I can try.

Thank you

Comment: Use a regular expression replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the preg_replace()-function

```
$result = preg_replace('/product\s+code[^>]*\>/is', '', $input);
```

Regular Expression

```
look for    "product"
followed by \s+ (one or more spaces, tabs,...)
followed by "code"
followed by [^>]* (an unspecified amount of charakters that are not ">")
followed by \> an ">" (\ is es for escaping)
```

Flag

```
i = ignore upper/lowercase
s = search multiple lines
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the following code:

```
$description = 'Flat sandal <br />Blush<br />Laminated leather<br />Intertwining straps<br />Low heel: 0.5cm<br />

        Product code: 5276870PS006703 <br /> Made in: Italy<br />Composition: 100%Calfskin';
$pattern = '/Product code:\s*\w*\s*<br />/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $description);
```

**final output:**

```
Flat sandal 
Blush
Laminated leather
Intertwining straps
Low heel: 0.5cm
Made in: Italy
Composition: 100%Calfskin
```

**Explanations:**

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is a php function that will replace in an input string a specific pattern defined by a regex by a replacement

The regex used `Product code:\s*\w*\s*<br />` [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/r6Kbh2/1) will match strings that starts by `Product code:` followed by some space chars, followed by some word chars, more space chars before ending by the html `<br />` ([Regex quicksheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [preg_replace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), which uses regex and give you a lot of power to target whatever you after.

**Something like**

```
$string = 'Flat sandal <br />Blush<br />Laminated     leather<br/>Intertwining straps<br />Low heel: 0.5cm<br />Product code: 5276870PS006703 <br /> Made in: Italy<br />Composition:';
$pattern = '/Product code: (w+) /i';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Hope that helps